# Vim expand selection by a paragraph

Tags: vim

If I have a visual selection in vim, how do I expand the selection to include the next paragraph? Also can I press <kbd>o</kbd> and do the same to select the previous paragraph?

Comment: Probably a better fit at https://vi.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Qix you're right I didn't know that existed...

Answer (score 7):

You can use the `ap` or `ip` text-objects for "a paragraph" or "inner paragraph". A paragraph is a block of text separeated by blank lines. `ap` also includes the blank lines after the current paragraph. There is also `{` and `}` motions to move amongst paragraphs.

So to get the next paragraph you can do `2}` or `}ap`.

For the previous paragraph, indeed, use `o` to go to the other end of your selection and `2{`.

You can also add a count to `ap`, e.g `2ap` will select the current and the next paragraph.

Comment: Ok so the tl;dr is just use `}` and `{`. I don't see the reason for adding `2` in some of the examples. `}ap` is different cause it replaces the selection.

Comment: because if you are in the middle of a paragraph and you want to include from here to the end of the next paragraph (which is how I understood your question), the first `}` brings you to the end of the current paragraph and the second `}` to the end of the next one.